colcon building error ros2
I am trying to run the launch file provided from SolidWorks urdf exporter but I can't seem to even build the project when I run colcon build.
running the command colcon build --packages-select <my_package>
I get returned this error.
--- stderr: simple_test_urdf                        
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake

Extra Information: This may or may not help. I am very new to ROS2 (humble version) and currently have ubuntu 22.04 installed. I've been only practicing using the Python examples so I may not have CMake dependencies (if they are needed at all).
CMAKELISTS.txt contents
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(simple_test_urdf)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package()

find_package(roslaunch)

foreach(dir config launch meshes urdf)
install(DIRECTORY ${dir}/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/${dir})
endforeach(dir)


Hello,
Can you provide more information s.a CMakeLists.txt file, your directory tree, etc. As you mentioned, you are working with Python pkg. Then why does the error come from the CMakeList?

will do, thanks. @aarsht7

Is this CMakeLists.txt provided by the package? I find it odd that there is find_package(roslaunch), but if it needs to be there, place it above catkin_package() and make it find_package(roslaunch REQUIRED) or try commenting it out. Also I think colcon usually uses ament_cmake, so maybe try generating a new package via the ROS2 tutorial

@sniegs will give it a go, although I am a little confused about your comment on colcon,  why would it be necessary to generate an entire new package?

oh sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant, you might try generating a new package to see how the CMakeLists.txt should look like for ROS 2 aka built with colcon.
